# How to render and navigate django based web pages with a click of button without refreshing the page (Ajax)

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, ajax

am doing a django project and I would like my navigation bar to be AJAX based in the sense that when I click the link of a particular page, the page is rendered without reloading/refreshing the original page.
I have tried to use the django redirect function but without success.

your help will be appreciated.